# Variable as function parameter in Python

Tags: python, django

I think example is worth more than words.

I want to rewrite this :

```
person = Person.objects.filter(email__contains="gmail.com")
```

somehow like this :

```
condition = "email__contains"
person = Person.objects.filter(condition="gmail.com")
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: do you mean `email_contains` or `email__contains`? it is inconsistently spelled in your example - or is it on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independently of django you could call

```
condition = "email__contains"
person = Person.objects.filter(**{condition:"gmail.com"})
```

instead of

```
person = Person.objects.filter(email__contains="gmail.com")
```

because `func(kw=arg)` means the same as `func(**{"kw":arg})`

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed! thx

Comment: You have a typo: `"email_contains" -> "email__contains"`

Comment: Not sure if inconsistent spelling was on purpose in the OP's examples - but my code examples only work with consistent spelling